# Plot multiple barchart in one chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot horizontal bar charts.
If i add more than one bar chart (the commented out line in code) then it is overlayed, but i need to cut the x axies into multiple x axis.
Here is my code so far and a sketch how it looks like now und how it should look like.
I think the piece left is the cutting of the x axies but i cannot find it in official documentation.

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df["yaxis"]=(9,10,22,24)
df["A"]=(0.3498,-0.46,0.38,0.9)
df["B"]=(0.85,-0.035,0.91,0)
df["C"]=(0,0.058,0.88,0)

len=df["yaxis"].size
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-3,3)
ax.set_yticks(range(len))
ax.set_yticklabels(df.yaxis)
ax.barh(range(len),df["A"].to_list(), color='r')
#ax.barh(range(len),df["B"].to_list(), color='g')
plt.axvline(x=0,color="black",linestyle='-')
plt.show()
```

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNJTB.png)

edit1:\ all value are between -3 and 3

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to put the plots into the same set of axes and have separate intervals for differing x values.

The simple solution that maybe you could work from is to just do 3 subplots side-by-side.  After you get that working, there are ways of tinkering with the `GridSpec` within subplots to collapse the subplots next to each other which will get you pretty close to a "combined" plot

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

y=(9,10,22,24)

a=(0.3498,-0.46,0.38,0.9)
b=(0.85,-0.035,0.91,0)
c=(0,0.058,0.88,0)

x=[a,b,c]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3,sharey=True)
for idx, ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.set_xlim(-3,3)
    ax.barh(y, x[idx], color='r')
    ax.axvline(x=0, color="black", linestyle='-', lw= 0.5, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

#### Yields:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can offset the position of the bars:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame()
df["yaxis"]=(9,10,22,24)
df["A"]=(0.3498,-0.46,0.38,0.9)
df["B"]=(0.85,-0.035,0.91,0)
df["C"]=(0,0.058,0.88,0)

n=df["yaxis"].size
height = 0.175
p1 = [t - height for t in range(n)]
p2 = [t for t in range(n)]
p3 = [t + height for t in range(n)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-3,3)
ax.set_yticks(range(len))
ax.set_yticklabels(df.yaxis)
ax.barh(p1,df["A"].to_list(), color='r', height=height, label="A")
ax.barh(p2,df["B"].to_list(), color='g', height=height, label="B")
ax.barh(p3,df["C"].to_list(), color='b', height=height, label="C")
ax.legend()
plt.axvline(x=0,color="black",linestyle='-')
plt.show()
```

[image]